# Mavericks Toggling Bluetooth Device Suspend Every 3 Seconds

Tags: mac, bluetooth, osx-mavericks

Since updating to OSX Mavericks, my Bluetooth audio devices have had an annoying problem. When no sound is playing through a connected Bluetooth device, the device will produce a popping sound every three seconds.

I tailed the Bluetooth logs, and it looks like the system is putting the device in power safe mode every three seconds, then bringing it out again shortly thereafter. Indeed, the changes in state correspond exactly with the pops.

Does anyone have any information on disabling this "feature"? Tho popping sound produced by the changes in state is incredibly annoying.

In case I'm understanding this wrong, logs follow:

```
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1988 Enqueue - BTStartIO for GT BT-Receiver
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:2000 Process next XPC command: 1
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:2092 ProcessXPC: startIO output (prev input:0 output:0)
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:983 Sample rate change 44100.000000->44100.000000
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudioAgent.m:543 [prepareAudio] audioSink:1
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudioAgent.m:633 [prepareAudio] Returning: 0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1103 [startAudio] sampleRate:44100.000000 isA2DPSink:1 SCOState:0 A2DPState:1 isSystemSleeping:0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1200 [startA2DPAudio] state:2
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:603 Sending Start
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:687 [startStream] mPairedEndpoint: 0x7fd54143d2a0, source: 1, state: 2
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:403 [testSetState] 2->3 returns 0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:1174 [Start]  endpointID: 1
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:427 [setSignalInProgress] isInProgress: 1
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:438 [setSignalInProgress] setting up timer with timeout: 3.000000
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:318 [Fragment] entry  Size: 3
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:374 [sendSignal] entry
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:348 [FragmentAndSendSignal] Ignored return:0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:711 [startStream] returning 0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:427 [setSignalInProgress] isInProgress: 0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:554 [AVDTP Response] -> Start
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamManager.m:422 START RESPONSE endpointID:1 acp-endpointID:63 status:0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:1682 START RESPONSE:  0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:403 [testSetState] 2->3 returns 0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudioAgent.m:1364 [stateChanged] 3
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:435 [setStatusTimer] setting...
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudioAgent.m:1183 [Start Complete]: 0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1103 [startAudio] sampleRate:44100.000000 isA2DPSink:1 SCOState:0 A2DPState:2 isSystemSleeping:0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1200 [startA2DPAudio] state:3
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1262 Streaming when already streaming?
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1423 initiateStreaming A2DPState:3
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:253 setSniffAllowed:0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1311 #ch:2 rate:44100 duration:0.011610
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:1306 [setDuration] duration: 0.011610  numFrames: 512
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1324 [setAudioFormat] Codec:0 returns 0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1463 [initiateStreaming] Current role is master
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:959 startAudioTransmit
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:1143 [recalculate] TXDelta: 0.007256 (MTU:672.000000  Se:118.000000  Ne:64.000000  Tx:0.011610  Nx:512.000000)
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1491 [initiateStreaming] exit 0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1517 [encodingThreadRoutine] going onto runloop
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1865 SendXPCResponse:0 replyMessage:1 xpcConnection:1 to method:BTStartIO
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:2000 Process next XPC command: 0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudioAgent.m:1217 [Start Complete] returning: 0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:690 [AVDTP Response] exit
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1565 Clear buffered audio
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudioAgent.m:241 Stop IO - set outputActiveBeforeSleep = NO
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1988 Enqueue - BTStopIO for GT BT-Receiver
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:2000 Process next XPC command: 1
Mon Mar 17 20:39:57 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:2013 Delay stop for 3 seconds


Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:2000 Process next XPC command: 1
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:2151 ProcessXPC: stopIO output. Input is 1
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1152 stopAudio isSCOActive:0 (SCO:0 A2DP:3)
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:648 Sending Suspend
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1386 [stopAudioEncoder]
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1552 encodeCurrentAudioBlock stop
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1523 [encodingThreadRoutine] exit
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:875 SetIsCommandInt: 1
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:403 [testSetState] 3->2 returns 0
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:1261 [Suspend]  endpointID: 1
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:427 [setSignalInProgress] isInProgress: 1
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:438 [setSignalInProgress] setting up timer with timeout: 3.000000
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:318 [Fragment] entry  Size: 3
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:374 [sendSignal] entry
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:348 [FragmentAndSendSignal] Ignored return:0
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:747 [suspendStream] returning 0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:427 [setSignalInProgress] isInProgress: 0
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:554 [AVDTP Response] -> Suspend
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamManager.m:451 SUSPEND RESPONSE endpointID:1 acp-endpointID:29 status:0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:1747 SUSPEND RESPONSE: 0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVStreamEndpoint.m:403 [testSetState] 3->2 returns 0
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudioAgent.m:1364 [stateChanged] 2
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudioAgent.m:1257 [Suspend Complete]: 0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:253 setSniffAllowed:1
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1386 [stopAudioEncoder]
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:1865 SendXPCResponse:0 replyMessage:0 xpcConnection:1 to method:BTStopIO
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudio.m:2000 Process next XPC command: 0
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] BluetoothAudioAgent.m:1283 [Suspend Complete] returning: 0x0
Mon Mar 17 20:40:00 201 [bluetoothaudiod:2236] AVSignalManager.m:690 [AVDTP Response] exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like no one has any leads on answering this for Mavericks, and I couldn't find anything else after looking around for a few hours.

On the bright side, this is fixed in the Yosemite developer preview.